# Locale setDefault() Risk in Java

Tags: java, setdefault

I got one application that can switch language between English and Germany. When in Germany language i want the currency display will auto convert into German format. Therefore in my program i have to do checking for the locale then convert the currency based on the language selected. I choose to use locale.setDefault() but i not sure whether this will has any risk or not based on below statement which i found. Can somebody advise for this?

Statement:
"Since changing the default locale may affect many different areas of functionality, this method should only be used if the caller is prepared to reinitialize locale-sensitive code running within the same Java Virtual Machine."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning means that if you've already had code that initialized based on a different locale, then it won't magically hear about the locale change and update. For example, if you already set up your title bar and menus and button labels in English and then call `setDefault(Locale.GERMANY)`, all of the text will still be in English. Your example sounds like you won't be changing the locale after startup, so just make sure that you call `setDefault` early, before you do anything that depends on the locale.